# Creating a path based Ingress on a GKE cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress

So I am in the process of migrating my bare metal cluster onto GKE and ran into an issue with the ingress. On my bare metal cluster, I used the ingress controller from [nginxinc](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress) which worked fine. Below is a sample of an Ingress file of a particular deployment:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
namespace: mynamespace
name: app-ingress
annotations: 
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
rules:
- host: myhost
    http:
    paths:
    - path: /dev/appname(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: app
          servicePort: 80
```

Basically, when a user types in `myhost/dev/appname`, `myhost` is resolved to a HAProxy server. The proxy then routes the request to the NodePort that the ingress service is running on.

I tried to do the same thing on my GKE cluster with the only exception being that the Ingress controller on the GKE cluster is exposed using a **LoadBalancer** as per the [documentation](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/installation.md)

However I get a `502` error if I try to access the URL.

**TL;DR:** Looking for the best way to access various applications (deployments) deployed on a GKE cluster using URL's like: myhost/dev/firstapp and myhost/dev/secondapp etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Kong Ingress** as your ingress controller on GKE for your path based ingresses. You can install **Kong Ingress** from GCP Marketplace. It is easy to integrate and also supports various plugins for authenticating, monitoring etc.

You'll get detailed information and installation instructions from https://github.com/Kong/google-marketplace-kong-app#basic-usage

Answer (score 1):

I would follow this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke) on setting up Nginx on GKE. The ingress looks like below:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-resource
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /hello
        backend:
          serviceName: hello-app
          servicePort: 8080
```

You should be able to access your app externally `http://external-ip-of-ingress-controller/hello`

Now to debug 502 issue verify that the health-checks from the Loadbalancer to your app is passing or not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will follow the guide and check and let you know.. I saw the guide earlier and the only reason I did not do it because it pertains to the Kubernetes Ingress controller and not the Ingress Controller from nginxinc. I don't have a problem with either, I just wanted to see if I could use nginxinc on GKE as well because it worked perfectly on my bare metal cluster. But I will go through the guide and update you on the status. Thanks again

Comment: This guide is for Nginx ingress controller only.. the annotation defines what ingress controller will be used if you give kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx it will use Nginx and if you don't give anything then it will use gke ingress controller